# Is there a way to return many columns with linear indexing in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose a 3-D matrix :

```
>> a = rand(3,4,2)

a(:,:,1) =

    0.1067    0.7749    0.0844    0.8001
    0.9619    0.8173    0.3998    0.4314
    0.0046    0.8687    0.2599    0.9106


a(:,:,2) =

    0.1818    0.1361    0.5499    0.6221
    0.2638    0.8693    0.1450    0.3510
    0.1455    0.5797    0.8530    0.5132
```

I use linear indexing to have many element at a time:

```
>> index1 = [1 ; 2 ; 1 ; 3];
>> index2 = [1 ; 4 ; 2 ; 3];
>> index3 = [1 ; 1 ; 2 ; 1];

>> indices = sub2ind(size(a), index1, index2, index3)

>> a(indices)

ans =

    0.1067
    0.4314
    0.1361
    0.2599
```

I would like to do the same thing, put return all the values of the first dimensions. The size of this dimension may vary. The return should be, in that case:

```
>> indices = sub2ind(size(a), ??????, index2, index3);

>> a(indices)

ans =

    0.1067    0.9619    0.0046    % a(:,1,1)
    0.8001    0.4314    0.9106    % a(:,4,1)
    0.1361    0.8693    0.5797    % a(:,2,2)
    0.0844    0.3998    0.2599    % a(:,3,1)
```

Any way to do that in MatLab?

Comment: `index1 = [1 ; 2 ; 1 ; 3];` is equivalent to `index1 = [1 2 1 3]';` (not a solution, but good to know)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ind1 = repmat((1:size(a,1)),length(index2),1);
ind2 = repmat(index2,1,size(a,1));
ind3 = repmat(index3,1,size(a,1));

indices = sub2ind(size(a),ind1,ind2,ind3)

indices =

 1     2     3
10    11    12
16    17    18
 7     8     9

a(indices)


ans =

    0.1067    0.9619    0.0046
    0.8001    0.4314    0.9106
    0.1361    0.8693    0.5797
    0.0844    0.3998    0.2599
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you want by doing linear indexing on the last two dimensions separate from the first two dimensions. Even in the 3d data block where you expect to reference by `a(:,:,:)` you can reference by `a(:)` (as you know) *or* `a(:,:)`. The following code finds the sub2ind for the last two dimensions then just repeats them using `meshgrid`. This ends up being very similar to the solution proposed by @tmpearce but explicitly shows the semi-linear indexing and uses `meshgrid` instead of `repmat`:

```
dim1 = 3;
dim2 = 4;
dim3 = 2;

rand('seed', 1982);
a = round(rand(dim1,dim2,dim3)*10)

% index1 = :
index2 = [1 ; 4 ; 2 ; 3];
index3 = [1 ; 1 ; 2 ; 1];

indices = sub2ind([dim2 dim3], index2, index3)
a(:, indices) % this is a valid answer

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:dim1, indices)
indices2 = sub2ind([dim1, dim2*dim3], X,Y);

a(indices2) % this is also a valid answer, with full linear indexing
```

Comment: On another note: it is always good to keep in mind that `meshgrid` is a special plotting-oriented version of `ndgrid`. Function `meshgrid` does the same as `ndgrid` but flips the last two outputs. This is because of the interpretational "mismatch" that exists between a plot-oriented or a data-structure understanding of your data; e.g. rows are the first dimension in arrays in MATLAB, but can also be considered as the y-axis (which is the second axes in euclidian geometry). This is why `meshgrid` flips the two outputs. Should you use `ndgrid` instead?